# How can I make google give me only top-level page results?

Tags: search, google-search

I would like to do a keyword search but with only top-level pages as result.

For example, I want `https://superuser.com` as a hit but not `https://superuser.com/questions/230975/` on my search.

Only that I don't want to restrict it to a single site, superuser up there being an example. I want to restrict it to top-level pages only.

Is there a pattern for Google web search to do this or in case there isn't, any other search engine that allows it?

Comment: This may work `site:superuser.com`.

Comment: The `site:superuser.com` syntax restricts results to those from superuser.com, but it will still include pages like https://superuser.com/questions/1408205. So I don't think that'll do what the questioner is asking for. (But it's a handy technique for other situations.)

Comment: I **do not** think that there is any functionality for top level only search as you can see [on google support](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) and [on ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/).